# Total number of words possible using inclusion-exclusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Calculate total number of words possible using alphabets A-Z having length 26 with following restrictions(Repetition not allowed)

- A and B should not occur adjacently (AB is not possible neither BA)
- D and E should not occur adjacently
- B and F should not occur adjacently
- L and M should not occur adjacently
- M and B should not occur adjacently
- K and A should not occur adjacently
- X and B should not occur adjacently

My first thought is to use Inclusion-Exclusion Principle. 
My thought process so far: Total number of words possible=26!
Total number of words possible taking each cases independently =25!*2 (multiplying by 2 because of AB and BA)
But after this I don't know how to proceed. Can someone give me detail explanation. I am looking for explanation rather than answer in such a way that this question can be generalized.

Comment: Is this for a live contest / where is this problem from?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: This looks quite complicated. My first thought is that many of the conditions involve A and B. So perhaps you should look at all the possibilities for what the immediate neighbours of A and B are, and then, (except in the case where A and B are separated only by one letter), treat these as blocks of two or three letters containing A and B. But you said you wanted to be able to generalize, so maybe this isn't the kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: @David I thought for a while that so. Maybe this question is leading to graphs? I tried to google lot about it but couldn't find, so I posted it up here. I don't know how to proceed graphs or inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to automate this for a computer, then the inclusion-exclusion principle is probably the right way to go, as long as the number of conditions isn't too high. Each time you try to evaluate the cardinality of an intersection (e.g., A adjacent to B, B adjacent to M, D adjacent to E), your problem will be to make words out of "blocks" ABM/MBA, DE/ED, C, F, ... If, instead of a block, you get a cycle, then the cardinality will be zero for that case.

Comment: Number of conditions is not too high but 7 conditions seems to be complex enough though. Could you explain more on how to "automate this for a computer"?

Comment: @Marcus I am sorry I don't know the answer. I read the similar question few weeks back. If you have generalize your approach you can share here.

Comment: I'm not a programmer, but here is the principle I have in mind. You have 7 conditions, so the I-E principle requires you to evaluate 128 cardinalities. Namely, for each choice of some subset of the conditions, you need to find the number of ways to satisfy those conditions. Each set of conditions will create links between letters, as in the example with A, B, M, D, E I gave. Then you must evaluate the number of ways to write a word with both ABM/MBA and DE/ED. There are 23 blocks, so there are $2^2 \times 23!$ possible words. $2^2$ because an order needs to be chosen for ABM/MBA and for ED/DE.

Comment: This question has much resemblance to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1600489 which is stated too generally, but where in a  comment its OP notes that only 7 pairs are actually excluded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permutation of n objects with restriction of adjacent pairs](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596947/permutation-of-n-objects-with-restriction-of-adjacent-pairs)

Comment: This appears to be taken from a CodeChef programming contest problem that was live at the time: https://www.codechef.com/JAN16/problems/SEAKAM.   CodeChef rules prohibit asking others to solve the problem for you.  (Note how the CodeChef contest promises there will be at most 7 excluded pairs, and how this question has exactly 7 excluded pairs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula to compute the answer.

There are 7 conditions. (I will actually consider the negation of each condition.) According to the inclusion-exclusion principle, the total number of words satisfying none of the conditions is the sum, for each subset of the conditions (of which there are 128, ranging between 0 and 7 conditions), of $(-1)^{\text{(number of conditions in the subset)}} \times \text{(number of words satisfying all the conditions in the subset)}.$

I will give an example to illustrate how the number of words can be calculated. If the conditions are "A and B adjacent", "B and M are adjacent", "D and E are adjacent", then the words will be formed from blocks ABM/MBA, DE/ED, C, F, G, ...
There are 23 blocks in all, and two ways to order the multi-letter blocks, so the corresponding number of words is $2^2 \times 23!$. If we get a cycle, such as BMAB, then there are no corresponding words. If we have a single letter connected to three different letters, e.g., BF, BA, BM, then there are no corresponding words.

More formally (this answer generalizes), let $\Gamma$ be the graph on the set of 26 vertices $\{A, B, C, \dots, Z\}$ with seven edges AB, DE, BF, LM, MB, KA, XB. Then the required number of words is 
$$\sum_{S} (-1)^{|S|} 2^{b_s} a_S!,$$
where the sum is extended over all subgraphs $S$ of $\Gamma$ without cycles such that any vertex has degree at most 2, and where $|S|$ is the number of edges in $S$, $a_S$ is the number of connected components of $S$, and $b_S$ is the number of connected components consisting of more than one vertex. (The condition on $S$ says that it can be broken into disjoint line segments and isolated points. $a_S$ is the number of line segments plus the number of isolated points, and $b_S$ is just the number of line segments. $S$ could in principle have anywhere between 0 and $|\Gamma| = 7$ edges, although 7 is impossible with the particular conditions in this problem.)

I'm not sure whether this can be further simplified. In your case, there are no cycles, and the only vertex possibly of degree $> 2$ is $B$. There are 88 subgraphs $S$ satisfying the conditions to appear in the sum.